# Why we can respecify size of array?

Tags: java, arrays

My teacher said that once we can once specify size of array and then we can't change size of it anymore. But if we have peace of code something like this,

```
Main:
int [] arr = new int[2];
arr = Func(4);

[] Func(int n):
int [] arr = new arr[n];
for(int i =0; i < n; ++i) arr[i] = i;
return arr;
```

Isn't it count as respecifying of size?

Comment: Your function is returning a different array. You didn't change the size of the one you created earlier.

Comment: Your code doesn't resize the array, it makes a new one.  You can't resize arrays, because by there nature, they require a linear span in memory (from n to n+length of memory addresses) - this is very obvious in things like C where you can do pointer arithmetic to iterate over an array (and really mess things up :P) - This is why structures like linked lists exist

Comment: @MadProgrammer, so in 3rd line I've  got  new array with size 4 , but with the same name arr?

Comment: @MaksSimple But, it's declared as a local variable to the function/method os it only exists within that context (and can supersede class level variable names).  Once the function returns the variable is no longer valid/accessible.  The assignment of `arr = Func(4);` moves what `arr` was initially pointing at to point to the new array array created in the function

Comment: @MadProgrammer , thank you, now I understand. <3